# Will there be a "sister-site" for general Q&A (i.e. a Yahoo! Answers killer)?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, stack-exchange, site-proposal

Programmers are known as early adopters, and since Stack Overflow is so successful, I think a general question and answer website open to the whole public will be extremely successful. Plus, I think that being built on a Microsoft stack, it would be bought by Microsoft in less than a year.

Comment: Isn't the phrase early *adopters* not *adapters*?

Comment: How is bobby formed?

Answer (score 36):

I can just imagine Joel and Jeff responding to a general q&a question:

**xxxHotChixxxx:** So like, I love my boyfriend sooooo much. I wan to get married and have 7 kids, but he says no. The other day he was lookin at my BFF Jillian, an he stared at her jus waayyyy too long. I think hes cheatin on me, but I want all those kids! What can I do!?!?!

BTW Im 13.

**Joel:** Well, now.  In your circumstance, you should apply what I like to call "The Joel Test for Relationships".  You need to rank this boyfriend of yours according to the results from this test, and compare it to offers from other "opportunities".

- Does he use "source" control?
- Can he make a "build" in only one step?
- Does he make daily "builds"?
- ...etc...
- Does he do "usability testing" with everyone in the hall?

It sounds to me he fails point #12.  Dump him.

**Jeff:** I'd give it another 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Dear HotChix: Children can be spawned using the System.Threading library in .NET. These require only one parent, so your issues with your boyfriend are superfluous.

Comment: You are right, but the fact is that Stack Overflow has "noise" (funny, subjective, non programming related) questions too and that does not lower from its value.

Comment: There's noise, and then there's this.  I just don't see Joel & Jeff wanting to manage their very own Yahoo Answers kind of community.

Comment: Yahoo doesn't want to manage it either.

Answer (score 11):

They have developed the [StackExchange](http://Stackexchange.com) engine which would allow for people to create whatever kind of StackOverflow-like site they wish. I do not think they have any intention of making a Yahoo Answers killer because in all likelihood it would end up just as bad. The entire idea of having a single site for absolutely everything brings far too much noise and not enough signal.

Answer (score 7):

You can [make one yourself](http://www.stackexchange.com/) this september.

Comment: Or so we thought.

Comment: Should be available in the next 6-8 weeks.

Comment: SE 1.0? Obsolete, yo!

Answer (score 3):

Typical questions would include "How is babby formed?"

Comment: how girl get pragnent?

Answer (score -1):

I still think that this would be much better than the alternative of asking on Yahoo answers!

Comment: Also better than: a poke in the eye with a sharp stick. But don't expect it to drive all the eye-poking sites out of business; some folks just stick with what they know.