# Could there ever be a Stack Exchange site that would be willing to answer any question?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stack-exchange, scope

Obviously not all questions can be considered questions of the criteria of one of the existing sites, and while [Area 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#History) is allowing users to create new sites to help fix this, I feel that it will be hard to create one for every question.

Would it be good for Stack Exchange to make a general Q and A for questions that do not fit criteria for any site, or would it just be better to go on something like [Yahoo Answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers) to get good answers for everyday questions?

Comment: Yahoo! Answers is already great. Why do we need a copy-cat?

Comment: It would help if you could give a few examples of questions that shouldn't get "their own" sites, but that would be worth posting on a single Stack Exchange site.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2753/will-there-be-a-sister-site-for-general-qa-i-e-a-yahoo-answers-killer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68893/a-place-to-ask-everything-on-earth

Comment: [Ask any question you like on any Stack Exchange site with this one weird trick!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed)

Comment: The answer is forty two.

Answer (score 8):

A site without scope: that sounds like a pile of garbage. With no rules the quality will hit the bottom. Another problem might be that there is not a single topic expert that can answer your question.

A knowledge base of useful questions and answers can't be created by just one person: it needs an active community to do so. That's why the proposal to beta to graduation stage on Area 51 is important. And let's be honest: the site is not about you getting your answer. We want to contribute something useful to the world.

Answer (score 6):

Our goal is not to create a home for every question; our goal is to make *good* homes for *some* questions. We're reaching a point of diminishing returns on new sites; many of the large subjects already have sites. It's a long-tail distribution of subjects.

It's simply not possible to enforce quality standards on an anything-goes site. As proof, see [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080820174408AAZkbcG).

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange sites feed off *expertise*. It's not practical to build a quality Q&A site that vaguely covers an infinite variety of disciplines. At the very least, you'd have to partition it out into sections for each discipline. You know, like sites.

There are a lot of questions out there that will never be a good match for Stack Exchange's model. Questions that just don't make sense or are too broad, for example.

For the questions that would be a good fit, but don't belong in any existing sites, I'd argue that there is a somewhat finite set of site-level categories you could vote for on Area 51, that would give you 90% coverage.

Just take your questions up a few levels. Instead of wanting for a site about handing nulls in C#, stretch out the scope into a programming site. Instead of one about late-80s BMW engines, try for automotive maintenance and repair. If you take out the scope a bit, there will typically be a point where you encounter a viable site-level category that contains a number of questions, but is still small enough to build a strong community. That's when you should post something on Area 51.